# How can draw a line in matplotlib so that the edge (not the center) of the drawn line follows the plotted data?

Tags: data-visualization, python, matplotlib

I'm working on a figure to show traffic levels on a highway map. The idea is that for each 
highway segment, I would plot two lines - one for direction. The thickness of each
line 
would correspond to the traffic volume in that direction. I need to plot the lines 
so that the left edge (relative to driving direction) of the drawn line follows 
the shape of the highway segment. I would like to specify the shape in data coordinates,
but I would like to specify the thickness of the line in points.

My data is like this:

```
[[((5,10),(-7,2),(8,9)),(210,320)],
 [((8,4),(9,1),(8,1),(11,4)),(2000,1900)],
 [((12,14),(17,14)),(550,650)]]
```

where, for example, ((5,10),(-7,2),(8,9)) is a sequence of x,y values giving the shape of a highway segment, and (210,320) is traffic volumes in the forward and reverse direction, respectively

Looks matter: the result should be pretty.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution using [matplotlib.transforms.Transform](http://matplotlib.org/devel/transformations.html#matplotlib.transforms.Transform) and [shapely.geometry.LineString.parallel_offset](http://toblerity.github.com/shapely/manual.html#object.parallel_offset).

Note that shapely's `parallel_offset` method can sometimes return a `MultiLineString`, which
is not handled by this code. I've changed the second shape so it does not cross over itself to avoid this problem. I think this problem would happen rarely happen in my application.

Another note: the documentation for matplotlib.transforms.Transform seems to imply that the 
array returned by the `transform` method must be the same shape as the array passed
as an argument, but adding additional points to plot in the `transform` method seems 
to work here.

```
#matplotlib version 1.1.0
#shapely version 1.2.14
#Python 2.7.3

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import shapely.geometry
import numpy
import matplotlib.transforms


def get_my_transform(offset_points, fig):
    offset_inches = offset_points / 72.0
    offset_dots = offset_inches * fig.dpi

    class my_transform(matplotlib.transforms.Transform):        

        input_dims = 2
        output_dims = 2
        is_separable = False
        has_inverse = False

        def transform(self, values):
            l = shapely.geometry.LineString(values)
            l = l.parallel_offset(offset_dots,'right')
            return numpy.array(l.xy).T

    return my_transform()


def plot_to_right(ax, x,y,linewidth, **args):

    t = ax.transData + get_my_transform(linewidth/2.0,ax.figure)

    ax.plot(x,y, transform = t,
            linewidth = linewidth,
            solid_capstyle = 'butt',
            **args)


data = [[((5,10),(-7,2),(8,9)),(210,320)],
 [((8,4),(9,1),(8,1),(1,4)),(2000,1900)],
 [((12,14),(17,16)),(550,650)]]


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)


for shape, volumes in data:

    x,y = zip(*shape)
    plot_to_right(ax, x,y, volumes[0]/100., c = 'blue')
    plot_to_right(ax, x[-1::-1],y[-1::-1], volumes[1]/100., c = 'green')
    ax.plot(x,y, c = 'grey', linewidth = 1)


plt.show()
plt.close()
```